# (ncurses) - Does mvwaddch() make calls to wrefresh()?

Tags: refresh, ncurses

I'm working on a small game project and by mere curiosity I commented the line that makes a refresh to the main `WINDOW` object.

```
while(game->state)
    {
      //Move into player
      params->mov = player_1;
      params->x = player_1->pos_x;
      params->y = player_1->pos_y;
      params->game = game;
      //curs_set(FALSE);
      player_1->key_move(params);

      //Move into player
      mvwprintw(p_info,y, x, "TERRAIN: [%c]", player_1->inplace);

      //wrefresh(main_scene);           /* THE LINE I DELETED */
      wrefresh(p_info);
      sleep(TICK);

    }
```

The game ran without problems and player updated its position graphically. `player_1->key_move(params)` eventually calls `wgetch()`, `mvwaddch()`, and `mvinch()`, nothing else (from `ncurses`). `wrefresh(p_info)` was commented after and, as expected, that `WINDOW` object never updated. I'm wondering if that function calls `wrefresh()` at some point. There's no direct indication of this in the manual.

If it does, are there alternatives to `mvwaddch()` that doesn't update the `WINDOW` object?

Answer (score 0):

According to `man wgetch`, and I quote:

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to wrefresh, wrefresh will be  called  before another character is read.

Because this is a game, inside the loop, and more concrete in the routine call to `player_1->key_move(params)` there are modifications to the `WINDOW` object. This is why the program is causing such behaviour.

I realised that game logic was depending on state from the `WINDOW`, so several reads/writes would potentially come in the future. All game logic is to be handled separately.